# CQ5 Sling default servlets, same extension but different accepts methods

Tags: servlets, aem

So I have 2 servlets annotated like this:

```
@Component
@Service(value = {Servlet.class, NonExistingResourceServlet.class})
@Properties({
    @Property(name = "sling.servlet.resourceTypes",
            value = {"sling/servlet/default"},
            propertyPrivate = true),
    @Property(name = "sling.servlet.extensions",
            value = {"xml"},
            propertyPrivate = true),
    @Property(name = "sling.servlet.methods",
            value = {"GET"},
            propertyPrivate = true))
```

For both I override the accepts method

```
@Override
public boolean accepts(SlingHttpServletRequest request) {
    String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(requestURI)){
        return requestURI.endsWith("/sevlet1.xml"); //different for the other servlet
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

IN CQ /system/console/servletresolver one of them is not resolved. Do I have to be more specific in configuration. The accepts method is not enough?
Found on [Apache Sling doc](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/servlets.html)

> If a registered servlet implements the OptingServlet interface, Sling uses that servlet's accepts(SlingHttpServletRequest request) method to refine the servlet resolution process.
> In this case, the servlet is only selected for processing the current request if its accept method returns true.

For one of them I added a selector and now the difference is made.
My question is why do I need to add the selector if I override the accepts method?

The 2 servlets are like this:
/content/myapp/sevlet1.xml
/content/myapp/sevlet2.xml

Comment: I never tried the OptingServlet approach, but the other option would be a ServletFilter: http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/filters.html Do you really need to have a fixed url ending? In my experience the best way to distinguish two sling servlets is with the use of selectors: http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/url-decomposition.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether the `/system/console/servletresolver` tool takes `OptingServlet` into account, you might also put a debugger breakpoint in your accept methods to check that they are actually called when the corresponding HTTP requests come in. Note also that your servlets need to be declared "`implements OptingServlet`", which I suppose is the case as you have an `@Override` annotation on your accepts method.

Note that an `OptingServlet` that checks the request URI is usually not recommended in Sling, dispatching based on resource types or selectors is the recommended best practice.

(edit:) You might also compare your code with the [example `OptingServlet`](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/launchpad/test-services/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/launchpad/testservices/servlets/RequestUriOptingServlet.java) from the Sling integration tests.

Comment: hi can you answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28361998/how-to-provide-custom-value-on-checkbox-in-cq5-dialog

Comment: Tried with "implements OptingServlet" but no success. Using the  /system/console/servletresolver  found that both requests are resolved to the same and only servlet. Using selectors or resource types is the way to go.

Comment: I knew that but why is there the option if it is not working? I wonder if I could set something up to make it work.

Comment: I have added a link to an OptingServlet example to this answer. As mentioned, you could also set breakpoints in your servlet's accept methods to check what actually happens.